# Connect to a Nest.js server inside a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm trying to create a container for a Nest.js server. For now,I only have the basic version of the server that creates automatically when you create a Nest project. I tried some things in Dockerfile and docker-compose, but when I start the container and go to browser to `localhost:3042` it says the page isn't working, but it should GET an object.

So right now, my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /microservices

COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json tsconfig.json
COPY src src
RUN ["npm","install","global","@nestjs/cli"]
RUN ["npm", "install"]

EXPOSE 3042

ENTRYPOINT ["npm","run","start"]
```

And my docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  server:
    container_name: server
    hostname: localhost
    build: ./
    ports:
    - "3042:3042"
```

I run `docker-compose up`, go to browser and it doesn't work.

The output of the `docker-compose up` command is:

```
server      | [Nest] 18   - 07/12/2019, 1:44 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
server      | [Nest] 18   - 07/12/2019, 1:44 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +26ms
server      | [Nest] 18   - 07/12/2019, 1:44 PM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +10ms
server      | [Nest] 18   - 07/12/2019, 1:44 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +7ms
server      | [Nest] 18   - 07/12/2019, 1:44 PM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +5ms
```

So it seems like inside something is going on and the app starts successfully.

I looked on some examples, the one from their documentation where python is used and another example with `Express.js`, but didn't help me.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what actually happens?  Are you connecting from a browser, or another Docker container?  On the same host or a different host?

Comment: I kinda followed the steps in here https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/ but for the Nestjs server. I expected that I'm connecting in the browser of my pc to the adress localhost:3042 ('cause i expose the port 3042 and in the docker-compose I'm mapping it to the same 3042 port) to receive the message of the GET method from my server, like in their example.

Comment: Is there a setting in your code or the framework to set a "bind address" or "listen address"?  If it's set to listen to only `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, your service won't be reachable from outside the container, and this needs to change to `0.0.0.0`.  (This is a common issue, but it is also just a guess; including enough code in the question for someone to reproduce the issue would be helpful.)

Comment: Ok, maybe I should have added some info about the Nestjs server. I just ran the command from their tutorial to create a basic server and that's basically all I have.
The tutorial is this one: https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using FastifyAdapter, and it so happens that when being inside docker, you have to specify the host as `"0.0.0.0"` instead of `localhost`. The thing is, you have to add the host as a second parameter, instead of concatenate the strings:

**WRONG**

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, new FastifyAdapter());
await app.listen("0.0.0.0:3000");
```

**CORRECT**

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
await app.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
```

Answer (score 1):

Nest is using the port 3000 by default, so I think that's the problem. You can try to change it in the main.ts:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3042);
}
```

or changing your docker configuration.
Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 3000/tcp
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  server:
    container_name: server
    hostname: localhost
    build: ./
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
```

Comment: In their documentation (with python) I see that they use a different port for server-app than the ports of the container (for app they used 6379, but for container 5000:5000). Anyway, I tried to use all kind of combinations with port, but none seem to work. I even tried putting 3042 for server and for docker 3042:3042.

Comment: Have you tried to delete hostname from docker-compose? What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having the same issue, my problem was that I added a second argument in app.listen

change it from this:

```
    await app.listen(this.port, this.host);
```

to this

```
    await app.listen(this.port);
```

solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're using process.env be sure you define specific port on your .env like:

```
APP_PORT=3000
```

---

@main.ts

```
 await app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT || 3000, '0.0.0.0');
```

And @nestjs/config added on your dependencies. Check more details from [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration).